# How can I facet wrap 4 seperate datasets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, linegraph

so I am having a bit of trouble with trying to facet wrap 4 different datasets. Each dataset represents one participant but I cannot figure out how I can combine these so they can be facet wrapped and share an x axis. Here is the datasets for each of the participants:

p03

```
structure(list(day = structure(c(18880, 18880, 18908, 18908, 
18911, 18912, 18912, 18913, 18913, 18914, 18914, 18915, 18915, 
18916, 18916, 18917, 18917, 18918, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921, 
18921, 18922, 18922, 18923, 18924), class = "Date"), trialtype = c("go", 
"nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", 
"nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", 
"go", "go", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "go"), mean = c(0.453363414634146, 
0.21005, 0.63720350877193, 0.8809, 0.624077192982456, 0.581956842105263, 
0.63065, 0.588196842105263, 0.607075, 0.540253289473684, 0.73215, 
0.529153097345133, 0.583133333333333, 0.538794736842105, 0.4409, 
0.522421428571429, 0.4792, 0.552129824561403, 0.5282, 0.512742105263158, 
0.473664912280702, 0.528580701754386, 0.544266666666667, 0.490643859649123, 
0.49955, 0.440738596491228, 0.475708771929825)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), groups = structure(list(
    day = structure(c(18880, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18913, 18914, 
    18915, 18916, 18917, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921, 18922, 18923, 
    18924), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 
        5L, 6:7, 8:9, 10:11, 12:13, 14:15, 16:17, 18:19, 20L, 
        21L, 22:23, 24:25, 26L, 27L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -16L), .drop = TRUE))
```

p04

```
structure(list(day = structure(c(18880, 18880, 18918, 18918, 
18919, 18920, 18922, 18923), class = "Date"), trialtype = c("go", 
"nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "go", "go", "go"), mean = c(0.453363414634146, 
0.21005, 0.51259649122807, 0.5512, 0.631542105263158, 0.635184210526316, 
0.718966666666667, 0.795638596491228)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), groups = structure(list(
    day = structure(c(18880, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18922, 18923
    ), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 5L, 
        6L, 7L, 8L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))
```

p05

```
structure(list(day = structure(c(18924, 18924, 18925, 18925, 
18926, 18926, 18927, 18927, 18928, 18928, 18929, 18929, 18930, 
18930, 18932, 18933, 18933, 18934, 18935, 18935, 18936, 18936, 
18937, 18937, 18940, 18941, 18941, 18942, 18944, 18944, 18945, 
18945, 18948, 18950, 18951, 18951), class = "Date"), trialtype = c("go", 
"nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", 
"go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "go", "nogo", "go", "go", "nogo", 
"go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "go", "nogo", "go", "go", "nogo", 
"go", "nogo", "go", "go", "go", "nogo"), mean = c(0.693312280701754, 
0.5485, 0.589122807017544, 1.26686666666667, 0.542644444444444, 
0.3142, 0.607622807017544, 1.0739, 0.562494642857143, 0.45075, 
0.522236842105263, 1.4405, 0.585782456140351, 0.574333333333333, 
0.549415789473684, 0.499456140350877, 0.89835, 0.571619298245614, 
0.836829824561404, 0.8192, 0.881107692307692, 2.16316666666667, 
0.600214035087719, 0.6608, 0.665928571428571, 0.633136363636364, 
0.4519, 0.558714035087719, 0.7840875, 1.20543333333333, 0.597352631578947, 
1.564875, 0.517835087719298, 0.533582456140351, 0.526968421052632, 
1.31243333333333)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), groups = structure(list(
    day = structure(c(18924, 18925, 18926, 18927, 18928, 18929, 
    18930, 18932, 18933, 18934, 18935, 18936, 18937, 18940, 18941, 
    18942, 18944, 18945, 18948, 18950, 18951), class = "Date"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 
        15L, 16:17, 18L, 19:20, 21:22, 23:24, 25L, 26:27, 28L, 
        29:30, 31:32, 33L, 34L, 35:36), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -21L), .drop = TRUE))
```

p07

```
structure(list(day = structure(c(19210, 19210, 19211, 19211, 
19212, 19212, 19213, 19213, 19214, 19214, 19215, 19215, 19216, 
19216, 19217, 19217, 19218, 19218, 19219, 19221, 19222, 19223, 
19223, 19224, 19225, 19226, 19226, 19227, 19227, 19228, 19228, 
19229, 19229, 19230, 19231, 19231, 19232, 19232, 19238, 19238, 
19239, 19239, 19240, 19241, 19242, 19242, 19243), class = "Date"), 
    trialtype = c("go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", 
    "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", 
    "go", "nogo", "go", "go", "go", "go", "nogo", "go", "go", 
    "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", 
    "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", 
    "go", "go", "nogo", "go"), mean = c(0.496695906432749, 0.54765, 
    0.44894269005848, 0.406666666666667, 0.444126315789474, 0.3496, 
    0.442609356725146, 0.4528, 0.462447953216374, 0.4262, 0.47875730994152, 
    0.464266666666667, 0.459146783625731, 0.261666666666667, 
    0.479398830409357, 0.4199, 0.48975730994152, 0.2944, 0.511256140350877, 
    0.49047485380117, 0.543529239766082, 0.513159064327485, 0.5597, 
    0.51296783625731, 0.478275438596491, 0.492419298245614, 0.1061, 
    0.49356432748538, 0.4948, 0.534784795321637, 0.5097, 0.509980701754386, 
    0.2998, 0.505461988304094, 0.52029649122807, 0.52315, 0.52303216374269, 
    0.5337, 0.517447368421053, 0.3997, 0.517894152046784, 0.696366666666667, 
    0.511729824561403, 0.5346, 0.515273684210526, 0.508, 0.552337426900585
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -47L), groups = structure(list(day = structure(c(19210, 
19211, 19212, 19213, 19214, 19215, 19216, 19217, 19218, 19219, 
19221, 19222, 19223, 19224, 19225, 19226, 19227, 19228, 19229, 
19230, 19231, 19232, 19238, 19239, 19240, 19241, 19242, 19243
), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 
    9:10, 11:12, 13:14, 15:16, 17:18, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22:23, 24L, 
    25L, 26:27, 28:29, 30:31, 32:33, 34L, 35:36, 37:38, 39:40, 
    41:42, 43L, 44L, 45:46, 47L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -28L), .drop = TRUE))
```

From the datasets, I started to create separate data visualisations for each participant which are as follows:

```
p03_dropped_rt <- p03_response_times %>%
  drop_na()

#convert day into date object 

p03_dropped_rt$day <- as.Date(p03_dropped_rt$day)

head(p03_dropped_rt)

#create a line graph for p03 to show this data but have the x axis as just days 

          
p3 <- p03_dropped_rt %>% 
  group_by(trialtype) %>% 
  arrange(day) %>% 
  mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(days), y = mean, group = trialtype)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title=" P03s Average response time of Go/No-go Trials",
       x = "Day of training",
       y = "Average Response Time (s) ",
       color = "Trial Type")

p3

# repeat for p04 

#drop missing values 

p04_dropped_rt <- p04_response_times %>%
  drop_na()

#convert day into date object 

p04_dropped_rt$day <- as.Date(p04_dropped_rt$day)

head(p04_dropped_rt)

#create a line graph to show these results 

p4 <- p04_dropped_rt %>% 
  group_by(trialtype) %>% 
  arrange(day) %>% 
  mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(days), y = mean, group = trialtype)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title=" P04s Average response time of Go/No-go Trials",
       x = "Day of training",
       y = "Average Response Time (s) ",
       color = "Trial Type")

p4

#repeat for p05 and drop missing values 

p05_dropped_rt <- p05_response_times %>%
  drop_na()

#convert day into date object 

p05_dropped_rt$day <- as.Date(p05_dropped_rt$day)

head(p05_dropped_rt)

#create a line graph to show this 

p5 <- p05_dropped_rt %>% 
  group_by(trialtype) %>% 
  arrange(day) %>% 
  mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(days), y = mean, group = trialtype)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title=" P05s Average response time of Go/No-go Trials",
       x = "Day of training",
       y = "Average Response Time (s) ",
       color = "Trial Type")

p5

# repeat for p07 and drop missing values 

p07_dropped_rt <- p07_response_times %>%
  drop_na()

# convert day to date object 

p07_dropped_rt$day <- as.Date(p07_dropped_rt$day)

head(p07_dropped_rt)

#create a line graph to show this 

p7 <- p07_dropped_rt %>% 
  group_by(trialtype) %>% 
  arrange(day) %>% 
  mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(days), y = mean, group = trialtype)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title=" P07s Average response time of Go/No-go Trials",
       x = "Day of training",
       y = "Average Response Time (s) ",
       color = "Trial Type")

p7
```

I was not sure how to facet wrap so I tried 'ggarrange'. However, this caused the graphs to be incredibly stretched out and did not look good visually. I have attached an image at the end if you would like to see.

Please can someone help me with this?

[image]

---

I tried binding the rows as follows

```
bind_rows(list(p3, p4, p5, p7), .id="patient") %>% 
  group_by(trialtype) %>% 
  arrange(day) %>% 
  mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(days), y = mean, group = trialtype)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title="Average response time of Go/No-go Trials",
       x = "Day of training",
       y = "Average Response Time (s) ",
       color = "Trial Type") + facet_wrap(patient)
```

it comes up with this error

```
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
```

Comment: Why not use ggarrange to plot in a 2 x 2 grid?

Comment: `bind_rows(list(p3, p4, p5, p7), .id="patient") %>%  <your graphing code here> + facet_wrap(patient)`.

Comment: @AllanCameron This was something I considered, but the data is going to be used for a presentation, the less busy the slide, the better and that may not be suited.

Comment: @Limey I tried your code but i dont think it worked, ill add it to the question so you can see

Comment: @JacobHad Allan suggested 2x2 grid because you don't seem to like the 4x1 stretched out grid. If you do want it 4x1 but, just less stretched, you know you know you can resize the plotting window, right? It's fitting the plots in to whatever size you window is. And when you save/export the plot you can specify the width.

Comment: You got the error in limey's code beacuse you need names to use the `.id` arg. `bind_rows(list(P03 = p3, P04 = p4, P05 = p5, P07 = p7), .id="patient") %>%  <your graphing code here> + facet_wrap(patient)`

Comment: My small mistake. My apologies. You need `... + facet_wrap(vars(patient))`, not `... + facet_wrap(patient)`, something you could have discovered instantly for yorself by reading the online doc: "facets 
A set of variables or expressions quoted by vars() and defining faceting groups on the rows or columns dimension. The variables can be named (the names are passed to labeller).".

Comment: @GregorThomas yep, did that and I'm still not happy with how it looks so trying to facet wrap it instead

Comment: @Limey that still didn't seem to work, comes up with an error saying all columns in a tibble must be vectors and column 'P03' is a ggplot object which show up for each participants data. And Im not sure what document you're referring to but I would love to read it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing, but it's obviously not right.

```
bind_rows(list(p03, p04, p05, p07), .id="patient") %>% 
  group_by(trialtype) %>% 
  arrange(day) %>% 
  mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(days), y = mean, group = trialtype)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title="Average response time of Go/No-go Trials",
       x = "Day of training",
       y = "Average Response Time (s) ",
       color = "Trial Type") + 
  facet_wrap(vars(patient))
```

Gives

[image]

To access the online help, use `?`.  For example `> ?facet_wrap`.  Or type the function's name in the search bar at the top of the help panel in RStudio.  Or use Google.

Comment: Im not sure either because that code still gives me an error: ```Error in list2(...) : object 'p03' not found```. I'll have a look on google and see if I can find a solution, thank you for trying anyway, much appreciated